# Zend Translate - Locale not working

Tags: zend-framework, zend-translate, zend-locale

I started working on a multilangual Zend Framework application and I've been stucked on something I hate:

```
The locale is not working like expected.
```

There's the .ini config:

```
; Locale
resources.locale.default = "fr"
resources.locale.force = false
resources.locale.cache = "locale"
resources.locale.registry_key = "Zend_Locale"

; Translate
resources.translate.adapter = Ini
resources.translate.content = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/locales"
resources.translate.scan = Zend_Translate::LOCALE_DIRECTORY
resources.translate.options.tag = "Zend_Translate"
resources.translate.options.logUntranslated = true
resources.translate.options.disableNotices = false
resources.translate.options.logMessage = "Untranslated message within '%locale%': %message%"
resources.translate.options.logPriority = 5
resources.translate.options.registry_key = "Zend_Translate"
resources.translate.cache = "languages"
resources.translate.locale = "auto"
```

My filename are:

```
/locales/en.ini
/locales/fr.ini
```

When I do a simple `$this->translate('COPYRIGHT');`, it always return the french translation. Even if my computer is in english. I tried adding `force = true` to the locale and changing it to `en_US` but without success.

Comment: As can see in your config file `resources.locale.default = "fr"`. Default locale is french.

Comment: Yup, but my browser is in english, and when I do `$translate->getLocale();`, I get `en_US`...

Comment: Are you check just before `$this->translate('COPYRIGHT');` ?

Comment: In my layout, in the footer, I exec `$this->translate('COPYRIGHT');` which is defined in both `en` and `fr` ini files.

Comment: Yes but I mean have you check `$translate->getLocale();` just before `$this->translate('COPYRIGHT');` what you getting ?

Comment: I tried also, and still getting `en_US` then the copyright in french...